# Checking If String Already Exists in Worksheet Column

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform that's supposed to validate new record entries to avoid duplicating data. I'm using Chip Pearson's FindAll (http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx) method to prevent a user from entering a record 
name if a matching record already exists in a worksheet column (Column "D"). If FindAll determines a matching string 
is already in the column, I want to disable the save button, change the background of the textbox containing the duplicate record
string, and display an informational label asking the user to change offending record entry. The problem that I'm having is that FindAll is 
not working as expected although I've confirmed a string matching the new record entry exists in the target
worksheet column. Could someone please explain to me why my FindAllMatches subroutine doesn't work as expected:

```
Const sDefaultRecordMessage As String = "Enter record name."

Private Sub tbRecord_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    'Calls the FindAllMatches routine as user types text in the textbox
    Call FindAllMatches
End Sub

Private Sub tbRecord_Enter()
    With Me.tbRecord
        If .Text = sDefaultRecordMessage  Then .Text = vbNullString
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub tbRecord_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    With Me.tbRecord
        If .Text = vbNullString Then .Text = sDefaultRecordMessage 
    End With

    Call FindAllMatches
End Sub

Private Sub FindAllMatches()
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim FindWhat As Variant

    FindWhat = Trim(Me.tbRecord.Value)

    Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.Range("D3").End(xlDown)

    'Calls Chip Pearson's FindAll function
    Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, _
                            FindWhat:=FindWhat, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            MatchCase:=True, _
                            BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare)
    If FoundCells Is Nothing Or Len(Me.tbRecord.Value) = 0 Then
        Me.lblDuplicateMessage.Visible = False
        Me.cbSaveRecord.Enabled = True
        Me.tbRecord.BackColor = &H80000005
    Else
        Me.lblDuplicateMessage.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Me.lblDuplicateMessage.Visible = True
        Me.tbRecord.BackColor = RGB(255, 204, 204)
        Me.cbSaveRecord.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveSheet.Range("D3").End(xlDown)` sets the search range to a single cell...

However, since you don't really need to count the number of occurences, it would be faster/easier to use `Match()` on the entire column:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Trim(Me.tbRecord.Value), _
                                 ActiveSheet.Range("D:D"), 0)) Then
    'have an existing match in ColD
End If
```

Comment: I want to exclude cells "D1" and "D2" from the search because they contain a header and row of macro buttons, respectively. Your solution searches all of column "D".

Comment: Is it likely they would contain the value being searched for if they are headers? But you could just use ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("D3"), ActiveSheet.Range("D3").End(xlDown)), instead of ActiveSheet.Range("D:D")

Comment: @Bob Phillips I agree it's not likely, but I would like to exclude those cells nonetheless. I'll try your solution.